# Mutt and calendar?

Tags: calendar, mutt

Is there any calendar which works well with Mutt?

Ideally it should be able to handle .ics files so I can import the meeting invitations my Outlook-using colleagues send me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use [remind](https://dianne.skoll.ca/projects/remind/) with mutt. I wrote a simple script that translates an Outlook calendar invitation to a remind event, appends the event to my `~/.reminders` file, and opens vim with `~/.remind` in one window and the invitation in another window for reference so that I can edit the remind event if desired. The script is invoked with a mutt macro.

When I receive an Outlook invitation, I type `,r` to invoke the macro, check in the resulting vim instance that the event looks OK, then close vim with `:qa` or if I've edited the reminder, with `:wqa`.

To display the calendar and to alert me when meetings are about to start, I use tkremind.

Comment: This sounds like awesome stuff. Could you share the script you mentioned? I am very interested in tweaking it to my needs. Thanks :)

Comment: @Shrikant Sharat: I have uploaded the script to http://www.spocom.com/users/gjohnson/mutt/mutt_add_reminder. Caveat 1: I wrote it to parse the Outlook messages that I received. I didn't use any other knowledge of Outlook, so it will probably need to be tuned for your environment. Caveat 2: I no longer work where I used that script and I don't use mutt where I work now, so I have no way to test any changes made to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am currently using outlook and preparing to switch to mutt. I'll try and figure the script out. Thanks again.

Comment: @garyjohn Too bad the link to this script does no longer work. It would have been very useful to me.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into it, but my ISP has not been very responsive.